# Как организовать доступ к объектам классов, объявленных в разных исходниках?

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте, у меня проект в VS2010, в нем несколько хидеров и cpp файлов.
В 2-х .h файлах есть 2 различных класса в 2-х пространствах, в 2-х cpp соответственно написаны функции. Функция майн находится в 3-ем cpp файле, в нем же обьявлены  обьекты классов и оттуда происходит их вызов. Беда в том, что я не могу получить доступ из 1-го cpp файла к обьекту из второго cpp и наоборот. Пространства подключал, делал даже элементы классов статическими. Ничего не помогло. А так если не вызывать - всё работает. Как быть в таком случае? Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наверно Вы хотели сделать что-то вроде этого?

```
//module1.h
#ifndef MODULE1_H
#define MODULE1_H

#include <string>

class Hello1
{
public:
  Hello1();
  void SayMyHello();
  void SayOtherHello()
  void fromMain();
private:
  string msg;
}

#endif

//module1.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "module1.h"
#include "module2.h"

Hello1::Hello1()
{
  msg = "Hello from module #1";
}

void Hello1::SayMyHello()
{
  cout << msg << endl;
}

void Hello1::SayOtherHello()
{
  Hello2 h2;
  h2.SayMyHello();
}

void Hello1::fromMain()
{
  cout << "This is a module #1" << endl;
}

//module2.h
#ifndef MODULE2_H
#define MODULE2_H

#include <string>

class Hello2
{
public:
  Hello2();
  void SayMyHello();
  void SayOtherHello();
  void fromMain();
private:
  string msg;
}

#endif

//module2.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "module1.h"
#include "module2.h"

Hello2::Hello2()
{
  msg = "Hello from module #2";
}

void Hello2::SayMyHello()
{
  cout << msg << endl;
}

void Hello2::SayOtherHello()
{
  Hello1 h1;
  h1.SayMyHello();
}

void Hello2::fromMain()
{
  cout << "This is a module #2" << endl;
}

//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "module1.h"
#include "module2.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  Hello1 hl1;
  hl1.SayMyHello();
  hl1.SayOtherHello();
  hl1.fromMain();

  Hello2 hl2
  hl2.SayMyHello();
  hl2.SayOtherHello();
  hl2.fromMain();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вроде проблема в том, что из второстепенного срр нет доступа в cpp с main()...

Comment: Вот тут я хочу, чтобы было не так


    void Hello2::SayOtherHello()
    {
    
      Hello1 h1;
    
      h1.SayMyHello();
    
    }

а вот так:

    void Hello2::SayOtherHello()
    {
    
      h1.SayMyHello();// обращаюсь к обьекту мейн...
    
    }

Comment: Тогда Вам надо внимательно изучить раздел языка про время жизни и область видимости объектов в программе. Одним из стандартных подходов в Вашем случае является следующий. Нужные объекты создаются как глобальные в одном из модулей. В остальных модулях они объявляются как extern. Например в main.cpp перед функцией main() создать: Hello1 hel1; Hello2 hel2; В модулях module1.cpp и module2.cpp сделать объявление: extern Hello1 hel1; extern Hello2 hel2; И всё - можно пользоваться.

Comment: Второй вариант - передавать объекты как параметры в функции.

Comment: О ЧУДО!!! C EXTERN РАБОТАЕТ!!! СПАСИБО!!!!

Answer (score 1):

надо чтобы каждый из тех двух h-файло включал другой, только не забудьте конструкцию вида:

```
 #ifndef MODULE_H_
#define MODULE_H_
//содержит описание класса   
#endif /* MODULE_H_ */
```

ичане в вас будет рекурсия изза включения заголовков

Comment: Да, там что-то такое... А тут вот //содержит описание класса 
что нужно писать??? Заново класс обьявлять?

Comment: да, внутри блока просто описание класса
class CFoo {
private:
//...
public:
//...
};

Comment: Что-то не хочет работать... Скажите а в другом файле переопределенный класс остается? Можно ли там(//содержит описание класса  ) написать #include"******.h" или исключительно класс...?

Comment: Вы берете 2 ваших хидера и просто обрамляете такой конструкцией.

Comment: можнопоподробней? В хидер 1 пишу:
 #ifndef MODULE_H1_
#define MODULE_H1_
//содержит описание класса хидера 2   
#endif /* MODULE_H1_ */

В хидер 2 пишу:
 #ifndef MODULE_H2_
#define MODULE_H2_
//содержит описание класса хидера 1  
#endif /* MODULE_H2_ */

Comment: Я походу ошибся, скорее всего придется два класса помещать в один заголовичный файл.

Comment: Вроде проблема в том, что из второстепенного срр нет доступа в cpp с main()...